# Logged into database 'yadi', but dbfilter rejects it; logging session out

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Good morning,

I'm working on odoo 8, I created a new database 'yadi' but nothing happens, I always get database manager web page, and this is error on open-server.log:

```
Logged into database 'yadi', but dbfilter rejects it; logging session out.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to remove *db-filter* from *openerp-server.conf*

For search mention, you need to use following command.

```
locate openerp-server.conf
```

Go to path and remove *db-filter* parameter.

Generally, that file located under */etc/* folder.

Afterwards, reboot your system.

Comment: Thank you @Odedra it's totally working I deleted these 2 lines from openerp-server.conf:
        `èdbfilter =^%d$`
        `#dbfilter = .*`

Comment: dbfilter is a necessary feature in a multi-database setup. Therefore this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am ODOO expert, It seems issue with nginx or apache2 configuration.

```
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
```

This header required in all proxy location. only / for this location not enough. All location with proxy_pass entry you need to add.

Even do for /web/static/ or website/static/ etc...

As ODOO multi host configured with dbfileter ^%h$, indicate all database based on host, so right header to forward.

In case you test without dbfilter, all works well but with dbfilter this may arise an issue.

Now follow my instruction, sure it will resolve ODOO bugs concerns.